# Killing a Specific browser from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have a process in which i am running a batch file which opens 1 browser. eg
"start iexplore.exe www.google.com" this will open ie with google on it.
and in other line i am running the same cmd with link to some other site "start iexplore.exe www.stackoverflow.com"

Now the situation is i want to Kill only www.google.com using batch file, with taskkill option or if any other option is there.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Google*"`

This one will kill all the processes (e.g.: IE, Chrome, etc..) with title starts with "Google".

If you run `start iexplore.exe www.google.com` a new IE window will open Google and the title will be "Google".

You can also be more specific to kill only Internet Explorer processes:

`taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Google*`

There are other filters and options you can use with `taskkill`. Check out the help `taskkill /?`

Comment: Observed one thing, when we minimize and trying to open the IE it will open a new one. it doesn't close the minimize one. is there any specific command to handle in minimize scenario too